# Difference in image meta data when using GEE compared to rasterio

Tags: google-earth-engine, rasterio, google-earth-engine-python-api, affine-transformation, geemap

I'm accessing SRTM image using GEE, and then I save it as raster and open again with rasterio.
I have realized that when I try to get the metadata with GEE, the values are different (and seem to be wrong) compared to Rasterio.

```
#with gee
img.getInfo()

>>>
{'type': 'Image',
 'bands': [{'id': 'b1',
   'data_type': {'type': 'PixelType', 'precision': 'float'},
   'dimensions': [43200, 21600],
   'crs': 'EPSG:4326',
   'crs_transform': [0.008333333333333333,
    0,
    -180,
    0,
    -0.008333333333333333,
    90]}]}

#with rasterio
src=rasterio.open('gs://my_bucket/imgs/elevation.tif')

src.shape
>>>(1397, 1553)

src.transform
>>>Affine(0.00026949458523585647, 0.0, -80.6661972311375,
       0.0, -0.00026949458523585647, 42.94423165191896)
```

As can be seen, the dimensions (shape) of the image and the transform are different.

How can I get the correct values from GEE?

The images both are elevation image , clipped to the same polygon

Comment: You seem to forget that GEE has exportation parameters that includes projection and region. Where are these parameters? SRTM image is on a global scale. It is clearly observed from **getInfo** information. However, the image information displayed with rasterio corresponds to a much smaller area.

Comment: @xunilk I haven't added this part to the script, the image is clipped to a specific polygon , and when visualize , they are the same (the small image and large image of gee)